# Seeking polygon shapefile of countries, states and islands?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, data

As often happens, the hardest part of GIS is to come up with clean shapefile with an attribute table.

I need to create a choropleth map, but all I have is this:

```
Domicile,Captives
New Zealand,24
Vanuatu,7
Hong Kong,3
Labuan,38
Micronesia,14
Singapore,64
British Columbia,21
Anguilla,252
```

As you can see, some of them are countries, some are US states and there are islands too.

The way I think of doing this is to first look for a world polygon shapefile of countries, then a shapefile of states and then look manually for what is left.

Is  there a shapefile that contains everything?

Comment: actually none of those are US States :-) before the Canadians come for you

Comment: checkout Natural Earth, http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Comment: http://www.statsilk.com/maps/download-free-shapefile-maps  or http://www.diva-gis.org/Data ,  what are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: @ed.hankins I have a client who wants a choropleth map. Not sure what he wants it for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the site *Global Administrative Area*. There, you can find surfacic shapefile for each country. Each country is divided according to its administrative divisions (ex: provinces). You can also download a polygon for the entire world.

http://www.gadm.org

Answer (score 4):

You can use the site free Global Data from this site. If you are looking for these countries there are some that are not here but a few may meet your needs.
https://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/gis-data-sources/

Also, ESRI just has their own open data on their website here: http://opendata.arcgis.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could use free and open OpenStreetMap data which is licensed under Open Database License (ODbL).

Keep in mind that OpenStreetMap is a community driven project so the data might in some cases be incomplete.

Mapzen offered a service where you could [download borders from every administrative unit within a country](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/), as a GeoJSON, file but that service has been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it directly on [IGISmap.com](https://www.igismap.com/download-free-shapefile-maps/). It provide free shapefile of country boundary, state boundary, Administrative and polygon shapefile.