# Looking for GIS dataset of Japan which includes smaller areas

Tags: data, japan

I have found several sources for GIS shp files which include Prefectures and Cities in Japan, these go to the Ward level i.e Tokyo > Shibuya-ku. What I am looking for is data that includes smaller areas within Wards, i.e Tokyo > Shibuya-ku > Harajuku

I have spent a long time looking around with no luck, does anyone have an idea where I can find this data?

Comment: What you want is administrative boundaries?
Check the global administrative areas at http://www.gadm.org/
Otherwise, you could download data from OSM

Comment: See if you can find what you are looking for. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182944/where-to-find-a-polygon-shapefile-of-countries-states-and-islands/182961#182961

Comment: @Albert yes administrative boundaries is what I need, I have checked gadm.org and OSM and even though OSM has building data they don't seem to go have polygons and attributes for the smaller town areas.

Comment: @Dan, did you succeed in finding this dataset in the end? (I am now trying to locate something similar, but with no luck either..)

Answer (score 3):

According to OSM's [wiki on Japan](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Japan_tagging#Boundary), OSM holds data for major and minor neighborhoods. You can download those data via the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) by using the QuickOSM plugin from QGIS or by using the [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) web application.

From the QuickOSM plugin, you can provide the required parameters in an interactive and quite intuitive GUI. The required key-value pair is

```
admin_level: 9
```

for major neighborhoods or

```
admin_level: 10
```

for minor neighborhoods.

If you would like to use the Overpass Turbo application, you can provide the following query:

```
<osm-script>
    <id-query {{geocodeArea:Japan}} into="area_0"/>
    <union>
        <query type="relation">
            <has-kv k="admin_level" v="9"/>
            <area-query from="area_0"/>
        </query>
    </union>
    <union>
        <item/>
        <recurse type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print mode="body"/>
</osm-script>
```

Of course, you can change Japan to a smaller area and change the administrative level by using `v="10"` instead of `v="9"` in `has-kv k="admin_level"`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [National Land Numerical Information](http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj-e/gml/gml_datalist.html) website. The website has most of GIS data at national scale at various levels.

Comment: Yes this is a good source of data for prefectures and wards but doesn't go down to neighborhood level.

Answer (score 1):

Geospatial Information Authority of Japan

http://www.gsi.go.jp/ENGLISH/index.html

http://www.gsi.go.jp/kankyochiri/gm_japan_e.html

Comment: Have tried data from here and it doesn't seem to go down to neighborhood level just wards

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a late reply but I found a good source for all small scale block names for the entirety of japan. It's quite useful. http://geoshape.ex.nii.ac.jp/vector-adm/

Answer (score -1):

I've spend most of the day also doing this. I noticed that Google Maps seems to split these areas based on even smaller polygons (see [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Masuura,+Abashiri,+Hokkaido+099-3119,+Japan/@43.9819914,144.2714653,14z/)). I think that they are doing this on the fly or something kind of like voronoi.

I think maybe the reason why there isn't a concrete dataset of the boundaries is because regions are set on a national level in Japan and so maybe the responsibility of designating smaller areas is ambiguous or seen as unnecessary? despite using the same character as town, machi is only a unit of address, not administration. I'm sure the shapefiles exist somewhere but I'm also not sure who would have them.

maybe Yamato Transport?

edit: a good phrase to use while searching is 地名データ

I found one which works for me. Maybe it will work for you

http://nlftp.mlit.go.jp/ksj/gml/datalist/KsjTmplt-N03-v2_3.html